# SQL Server: Running CONTAINS against a substring of a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table `table1` with an nvarchar column `column1` that looks something like this:

```
phrase 1.1;phrase 1.2;phrase 1.3 ...
phrase 2.1;phrase 2.2;phrase 2.3 ...
...
```

I would like to run an `CONTAINS` query on only the first phrase in the column. I've tried several variations of this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE CONTAINS(LEFT(table1.column1, CHARINDEX(';', table1.column1) - 1), <search query>)
```

Is this possible? Ideally, I'd like to do it without creating a new table or column.

Edit -- Some of the errors I'm getting:
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.`, `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.`, `Incorrect syntax near ";". Expecting '(', or SELECT.`

Comment: Without actually running it, offhand this query looks right. What exactly is the issue with it? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: @Mureinik Sorry, should have put that in the post. Several different errors. `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.`, `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.`, `Incorrect syntax near ";". Expecting '(', or SELECT.`

Answer (score 0):

The `CONTAINS` function is only used when the table (column?) is configured to use full-text indexing. I'm going to guess that this is not the case, here. (Apologies if it is--I have no experience with full-text indexing.)

In any case, as you are matching the first characters in the string, the more precise function `LEFT` should work fine:

```
SELECT *
 FROM table1
 WHERE LEFT(table1.column1, CHARINDEX(';', table1.column1) - 1) = @SearchQuery
```

Note that you may have problems if there are no semicolons in the string. One way to avoid that would be to guarantee there is always one present, like so:

```
SELECT *
 FROM table1
 WHERE LEFT(table1.column1 + ';', CHARINDEX(';', table1.column1) - 1) = @SearchQuery
```

Comment: It is full-text indexed, but I'm guessing taking the substring messes with that. I might just have to do it this way, but I was hoping to use CONTAINS to have a more advanced search. Thanks!

Comment: I defer to @Richard's opinion regarding the complexity of the `CONTAINS` function. Regardless, searching by the first N characters of a string is pretty trivial and shouldn't require full text indexing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a couple of problems here.  You can only use `CONTAINS` on a full-text indexed column.  If your table is configured that way then great!

Your second issue is that the `CONTAINS` syntax is a bit clunky, and it doesn't like complexity.  You could work around that using a common-table expression, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (column1 NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'phrase 1.1;phrase 1.2;phrase 1.3;'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 'phrase 2.1;phrase 2.2;phrase 2.3;'
SELECT LEFT(column1, CHARINDEX(';', column1) - 1) FROM @table;
WITH x AS (SELECT LEFT(column1, CHARINDEX(';', column1) - 1) AS search FROM @table)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE CONTAINS(x.search, 'phrase 1.2');
```

Noting that this won't work, because @table.column1 isn't full-text indexed.  But it gets around the syntax error, and could be adapted for your case.  Something like this:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT LEFT(column1, CHARINDEX(';', column1) - 1) AS search FROM table1)
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE CONTAINS(search, <search query>)
```

Comment: In this case, `search` *(computed column)* should be full-text indexed?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, this isn't going to work either, because of the substring.